# mocking a method call within PreAuthorize annotation

Tags: spring-security, mockito, jmockit

```
 @Test
 public void getValueTest() throws Exception {
     Request request = new Request();
     Response response = new Response();
 }
```

service class:

```
@PreAuthorize("(hasRole(@role.one) or (hasRole(@role.two) or hasRole(@role.three))) and @role.check(#requestObject)")
public Response getValue(Request requestObject) {
}
```

CheckRole class:

```
public boolean checkReturn(Request requestObject) {
    Boolean response = true;
    List<ReturnValueType> returnValueType = requestObject.getReturnType();
    String role = Validator..getRole();

    return response;
 }
```

Mocking is failing at `checkReturn` method of java as Validator is not having any roles.

Is there a way that we can mock the method call inside preauthorize annotation? Mocking the entire Role.java is not working as it is failing the other cases.

Comment: Perhaps this helps you testing your PreAuthorize: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22527978/how-do-i-unit-test-spring-security-preauthorizehasrole

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz referenced solution is about web layer, while question is about service layer

Comment: @user3927150 have you found a solution?

Comment: I have encountered the same problem and can't find a solution. Has anyone found a way to do this ?